# Grab Text storing it in a var then adding html method and adding animation to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to know the correct way to finish up this code at the bottom. I'm thinking there has to be a better way to grab content from one section of your site and displaying it somewhere else with animation attached to it. The Code below seems like it can do better. I post the entire code below, but you might be able to understand what i'm trying to accomplish just by reading this few lines of code. I left comments to help

```
// Find what input field was clicked
var formVaule = $('input[value="' + ValUe + '"]');

// Find the content and store it.
var k = formVaule.next().text();

// Display H2 tag with the content that was stored 
$('#' + ValUe).html('<h2>' + k + '</h2>');

// Animated the h2 tag with a background color
$('#' + ValUe).find('h2').animate({ backgroundColor: "#40822B" }, 100, 

// Call a callback function with the attention of removing the background.
function() {

    $('#' + ValUe).find('h2').animate({  backgroundColor: "white"}, 500);

});
```

Full code Below

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="informed"/>
    <span>INFORMED CONSENT</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="release"/>
    <span>RELEASE OF INFORMATION</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="intake"/>
    <span>INTAKE FORM</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="checklist"/>
    <span>CHECKLIST OF CONCERNS (CHILD & ADOLESCENT AND ADULT)</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="health"/>
    <span>HEALTH INFORMATION PRIVACY FORM</span><br />
</form>

<div id="informed" class="Form">1</div>
<div id="release" class="Form">2</div>
<div id="intake" class="Form">3</div>
<div id="checklist" class="Form">4</div>
<div id="health" class="Form">5</div>
<div id="ContactFormSix" class="Form">6</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
var myForm = new Array("INFORMED CONSENT","RELEASE OF INFORMATION","INTAKE FORM");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').on( 'change', function () {
        //check
        var ValUe = $(this).val();
        $('.Form').hide();
        $('#' + ValUe).show();

        //Find the value of the input that was clicked
        var formVaule = $('input[value="' + ValUe + '"]');

        //Grab the value of the input that was clicked and find the next element and retreive the text
         var k = formVaule.next().text();

        //Prepend the elemnts text
        $('#' + ValUe).html('<h2>' + k + '</h2>');

        $('#' + ValUe).find('h2').animate({ backgroundColor: "#40822B" }, 100, function() {
            $('#' + ValUe).find('h2').animate({  backgroundColor: "white"}, 500);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you are requesting the element `# + ValUe` 4 times. That means jQuery need to search to the entire DOM 4 times to get an element. Cache the value of this element and use that cache variable:

```
var elem = $('#' + ValUe);

elem.html(...);

elem.find(...);
```

`$(this)` inside the callback of the `.animate` method refers to the animated element, you don't need to use `$('#' + ValUe).find('h2')` again, just use `$(this)`.

You use `formVaule` once, just use that constructor instead of saving it to a variable.

To complete correct code:

```
var k = $('input[value="' + ValUe + '"]').next().text();
var elem = $('#' + ValUe);

// Display H2 tag with the content that was stored 
elem.html('<h2>' + k + '</h2>');

// Animated the h2 tag with a background color
elem.find('h2').animate({ backgroundColor: "#40822B" }, 100, function() {
    // Call a callback function with the attention of removing the background.

    $(this).animate({  backgroundColor: "white"}, 500);

});
```